# using Stanfordcorenlp occurs PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, error-handling, stanford-nlp

I am doing a project related to NLP, and I decide to use standfordcorenlp. However, when I try to implement these piece of code there exists an error. Following is my code and what printed on the console:

```
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'/Users/xiehang/PycharmProjects/Autism/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27')
sentence = 'Enviroment is really important.'
print (nlp.ner(sentence))
nlp.close();
```

And the console prints out:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
>   /Users/xiehang/PycharmProjects/Autism/NER.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py",
>   line 330, in wrapper
>       return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py",
>   line 515, in connections
>       rawlist = cext.proc_connections(self.pid, families, types) PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/xiehang/PycharmProjects/Autism/NER.py", line 9, in 
>       nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'/Users/xiehang/PycharmProjects/Autism/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27')
>   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stanfordcorenlp/corenlp.py",
>   line 79, in **init**
>       if port_candidate not in [conn.laddr[1] for conn in psutil.net_connections()]:   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/**init**.py",
>   line 2108, in net_connections
>       return _psplatform.net_connections(kind)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py",
>   line 249, in net_connections
>       cons = Process(pid).connections(kind)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py",
>   line 335, in wrapper
>       raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name) psutil._exceptions.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=707)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have searched almost all possible sites trying to figure it out for several days and it is very painful.  I really hope someone can help me figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Similar or possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100525/psutil-accessdenied-error-while-trying-to-load-stanfordcorenlp/49576614#49576614

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems, and I got this resolved by running the code through sudo. Here is my case:

```
sudo /Users/edamame/workspace/git/chinese_nlp/venv/bin/python3 chinese_segmenter.py
```

So you will be doing:

```
sudo /Your_python_location/python3 /Users/xiehang/PycharmProjects/Autism/NER.py
```

Hope this works for you as well.